# Validation does not work on HMVC Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, validation, codeigniter

I am new on HMVC Codeigniter.I would use the codeigniter for form validation on HMVC format of codeigniter but it does not show any effect that means formvalidation not work on my project. But this code should be work on MVC codeigniter.
So please help me to solve this problem in my project.I am greatful who help to solve this problem in my project.

** I have an associative controller file feedback.php as below**

```
 function index($offset=0){
         $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','trim|valid_email|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message','trim|required');

            if($this->form_validation->run()){

                $data1=array(
                    'name' => $this->input->post("name"),

                    'email' => $this->input->post("email"), 

                    'message' => $this->input->post("message"),

                );


                }

            }
            $data=array('body1'=>'feedback');
             $this->load->view('temp',$data);

        }
```

**I have an associative view file feedback.php as below**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url()?>"  name="FeedbackForm" method="post">

   <span style="color:#F00">

    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

    </span>
                    <table>

                        <tr>
                        <td><label>Name</label></td>
                        <td><input  id="name" name="name" type="text" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><label>Email</label></td>
                        <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td><label>Message</label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="message" rows="2" cols="16" ></textarea></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" /> </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                    </form>
```

Comment: Did you include route and libraries that are essential for HMVC patterns? Once again check HMVC configuration

Comment: Yes, I do it. But it does not work.

Comment: You have got a couple of close brackets you best to have else like below in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases with HMVC you may need to use MY_Form_Validation Library. If also using callbacks in form validation with HMVC will not work unless have code below.

And if learning best to use codeigniter 2.2.1 version codeigniter 3 coming out but still few bugs in it.

The other thing to note is you may need to configure your routes in config/routes.php

```
$route['feedback'] =  "module-folder-name/feedback/index";
$route['feedback/updates/(:any)'] =  "module-folder-name/feedback/updates/$1";
$route['feedback/add'] =  "module-folder-name/feedback/add";
$route['feedback/delete'] =  "module-folder-name/feedback/delete";
```

**On form change site url to base_url()** base_url with controller name that set in routes.php

On Your Form

```
<?php echo base_url('feedback')?>
```

Also why do you need `$offset=0` Look into uri segments if need to get ids from url.

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function run($module = '', $group = '') {
        (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI = &$module;
        return parent::run($group);
    }

}
```

And then in the controller would be `run($this)`

```
class Feedback extends MX_Controller {

public function index() { 

$this->load->helper('url'); // Try autoloading it
$this->load->helper('form'); // Try autoloading it
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email Address','trim|valid_email|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message','trim|required');

if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

// Load Main View & Data.

$this->load->view('folder/feedback');    

} else {

// Load Success View Or Redirect

$this->load->model('module-name/model_feedback');

$this->model_feedback->update();

// Or

$this->model_feedback->insert();

redirect('controller-name');    

}

}

}
```

**Model**

```
public function update() {
$data = array(
'username' => $this->input->post('email'),
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'message' => $this->input->post('message')
);

$this->db->where('your_id', $your_id); // May be uri segment() etc read userguide
$this->db->update('tablename', $data);
}

public function insert() {
$data = array(
'username' => $this->input->post('email'),
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'message' => $this->input->post('message')
);

$this->db->insert('tablename', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('feedback')?>"  name="FeedbackForm" method="post">

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<table>
<tr>
<td><label>Name</label></td>
<td><input  id="name" name="name" type="text" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Email</label></td>
<td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Message</label></td>
<td><textarea name="message" rows="2" cols="16" ></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" /> </td>
</tr>


</form>
```

Codeigniter Forum : http://forum.codeigniter.com/
Codeigniter 2.2.1 User Guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer.

Comment: Quite valuable answer, still working with Codeigniter 3.x.